# python sqlite foreing keys not deleting on cascade

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, foreign-keys, sql-delete

So I have 2 files, a client and a db class:

```
import sqlite3
from os.path import isfile

class Database:
 def __init__(self, db_name):
    self.db_name = db_name
    self.check = self.__check_db()
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name, check_same_thread=False)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    if not self.check:
        self.__create_db()

 def query(self, query, args=()):
    self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    result = self.cursor.fetchall()
    self.conn.commit()
    return result

 def __check_db(self):
    return isfile(self.db_name)

 def __create_db(self):
    self.cursor.executescript("""
                        PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;
                        
                        CREATE TABLE utilizadores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, senha TEXT);
                        
                        CREATE TABLE artistas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_spotify TEXT, nome TEXT);
                        
                        CREATE TABLE musicas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_spotify TEXT, nome TEXT, id_artista INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(id_artista) REFERENCES artistas(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
                                                        
                        CREATE TABLE avaliacoes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sigla TEXT, designacao TEXT);
                            
                        CREATE TABLE playlists (id_user INTEGER, id_musica INTEGER, id_avaliacao INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id_user, id_musica), FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES utilizadores(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_musica) REFERENCES musicas(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_avaliacao) REFERENCES avaliacoes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
                        
                        INSERT INTO avaliacoes (id, sigla, designacao) VALUES (1, "M", "Medíocre"), (2, "m", "Mau"), (3, "S", "Suficiente"), (4, "B", "Boa"), (5, "MB", "Muito Boa");
                        """)
```

and the client;

```
from database import Database

db = Database("spotify.db")

db.query("insert into artistas (id_spotify, nome) values (?, ?)", ("1", "The Beatles"))
db.query("insert into musicas (id_spotify, nome, id_artista) values (?, ?, ?)", ("m1", "Hey Jude", 1))

db.query("delete from artistas where id = ?", (1,))
```

If I do the last query because of the foreign key it should delete the music as well but for some reason it doesn't. I don't know the reason for why it's doing it since I have PRAGMA fk = on and I'm on the same connection

---

artistas --> artists

---

musicas --> musics

Comment: We please write out the last query. Hence instead of saying if I execute last query say if I execute the following query: db.query("delete from artistas where id = ?", (1,)) and then explain what issue are you facing. This will help someone to know the exact portion of the code you are facing issue in and helps to make your question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON` operates on a *per connection basis* and this means that you must set it for every connection object that you obtain (if you want the behavior that it provides, otherwise don't set it because it may decrease performance).

Inside the `Database` class define:

```
def set_foreign_keys(self)
    self.conn.execute("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON")
```

and use it in the client:

```
from database import Database

db = Database("spotify.db")
db.set_foreign_keys()

db.query("insert into artistas (id_spotify, nome) values (?, ?)", ("1", "The Beatles"))
db.query("insert into musicas (id_spotify, nome, id_artista) values (?, ?, ?)", ("m1", "Hey Jude", 1))

db.query("delete from artistas where id = ?", (1,))
```